# Apache using old PHP version

Tags: php, apache

When I execute phpInfo.php  script on my Linux (fedora)

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

It gives PHP Version 5.5

Whereas when I reach it using my Apache server (via browser) it gives me old PHP 5.3 version.

Found that Apache is using some library (LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so) - found it in php.conf.

Can anyone help how to change version Apache is using?

Or is there another way to force Apache to use another version of PHP?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: apache loads whatever php module you tell it to. if you want an older module loaded, then point apache at that older module.

Comment: Okay, but I don't have any other module. I have only the libphp5.so module. And libphp5.so is using php 5.3 (I assume - according to the php info on web)

Answer (score 2):

First, I'm not that familiar with package management on Fedora, so perhaps someone else can check the commands I've listed below.

On Debian, there are (at least) two different PHP packages:

```
php5-cgi - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (CGI binary)
php5-cli - command-line interpreter for the php5 scripting language
```

When you run your script from the command line, you're executing the second one of these. When you run your script via Apache, you're executing the first.

I've never known these to get out of sync - I've always seen both with the same version - but it doesn't sound like something impossible. I can imagine that if I really wanted to, I could figure out how to install different versions of both.

From my (limited) knowledge of package management on Fedora, I'd start by trying to update both packages to the latest version:

```
yum update php5-cgi
yum update php5-cli
```

Again, these may be named differently in the Fedora repositories, so you'll need to research that a little.

Comment: Yeah this could be it. I just created simlink from /usr/bin/php to php55. Because I though Apache is using the file  - /usr/bin/php too.  I can't use yum update sadly. Do you think there is some way to specify php5-cgi to use php55?

Comment: `/usr/bin` hold the command line binaries. The Apache modules are in `/usr/lib/httpd/modules/` or `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/`. (Don't know the exact location on Fedora).

Comment: Yeah I know that, what I dont know is how to force Apache to use different version of php :/ do you think it is possible just to link module with binary in /usr/bin? (not sure what these modules are)

Comment: I'd probably just remove (and purge - is that an option for `yum`?) the existing packages (Apache & PHP5), then reinstall and let the package manager sort it out.